# AutoWire services_test.yaml -> There is no node with id 'service.a'

Tags: symfony, symfony4

having trouble to get unit tests working after migrating to AutoWire in SF4.2
normal route works fine.

services.yaml:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means

# enable AW on controllers
    KRNApiBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

# AutoWireAliases
    MyClass: '@service.a'

    service.a:
      class: MyClass
```

services_test.yaml, has some, but not service.a defined/overloaded

running, any test, it fails at (WebTestCase):

`$client = static::createClient();`

`InvalidArgumentException: There is no node with id "service.a".`

when i copy the definition of `service.a`  to `services_test.yaml` - it works.
however i want, and have to avoid, defining all services twice (introduces a huge surface for errors)

Comment: It looks like circular definition.

Comment: hmmm, not sure, if i set -> _default.public to true (in the main services.yml) - it works

Comment: Personally, I prefer that too, cause the feature it not really useful and don't use any duplicates like services_tests.yaml, but Symfony folks would hate me :)

Comment: Before I used to work with compiler pass, that would make services public just for tests: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/05/17/how-to-test-private-services-in-symfony/#quot-what-about-compiler-pass-quot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug - should be fixed by https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/29393

Answer (score 0):

it somehow solved it self, after finding a controller and a service that still used the ->get() weird.